# php Cookies do not reset on some pages

Tags: php, cookies, reset

I am working on a login page.
When you logged in your name and your rank will be saved in cookies with a timer of 300 (5 mins). Now when you log out of your account you go to the logout page where your cookies will be reset and than you header in to the login page. Now when you got the link of the admin page you can just get in to it when there was a admin logged in 5 mins ago. So what i did is I did a echo on the login page for your rank but it showed nothing. But when i go to the link of the admin page it says that I am a admin when i did not log in. Does anyone know why it does this?
I got some printscreens here (the vars are in dutch).

[When you are logged in it will look in the database what your rank is (Rechten)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVOMu.png)

[Here is when you are on the admin page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HExqX.png)

I hope that anyone can help with this. If you need more info just ask.

Comment: Have you considered storing the name and rank in the session array?

Comment: SpacePhoenix well,  I first did but I  want it so when you are not active than you log out.

Comment: When someone logs out you could unset them from the session array

Comment: Yeah I know but it doesn't have a timer. When you login to a site and you just look at the page but don't click anything for a amount of time you automatically log out. That is what I want and I don't thing you can do it with sessions.

Comment: If you have access to cron jobs, you could have a cron job run every say 10 mins which would log out anyone who's not clicked anthing over the previous 10 mins

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you did before but on the logout page you should unset the cookie as shown below.

```
unset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]);

Or 

$res = setcookie($cookie_name, '', time() - 300);
```

Let us know if it helps.

Comment: yes i did, when you click on the logout button you are send to the logout page where this code is: <?php
session_destroy();
setcookie("Rechtenn", "", time() - 300);
setcookie('Rechtenn', "", - 300, '/');
unset($_COOKIE['Rechtenn']);
setcookie("Naam", "", time() - 300);
setcookie('Naam', "", - 300, '/');
unset($_COOKIE['Naam']);
header('location: index.php');
?>
Than you are going to the index. On the index i have a echo of the cookie rechten. And there is does not say anything. So cookie is gone, but when i go the the admin site without logging in it says that i got the cookie...